# Sudden drop of pageviews/visit and increase of bounce rate in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, statistics

Google analytics stats:

04 june 2012

- Visits: 4.423
- Unique visitors: 3.558
- Pageviews: 77.352
- Pageviews / visit: 17,49
- Visit length: 00:06:26
- Bounce rate: 1,09%

05 june 2012

- Visits: 4.652
- Unique visitors: 3.825
- Pageviews: 45.087
- Pageviews / visit: 9,69
- Visit length: 00:06:45
- Bounce rate: 19,60%

From one day to another the bounce rate went from 1% to 19%, the pageviews dropped by half so did the pageviews/visit.

The only thing I changed (If I remember correctly) on the site, was an advertisment that used a javascript.

Could this be the reason? and, if it is, how can I know which one is the real stats?

Comment: Are they landing on the same landing pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your site was running particularly slowly and people got frustrated and left.  Have you checked any server performance reports?

Comment: No i didn't have any complaints or anything that suggests that the site was slow...

Answer (score 1):

you could try running an alternative analytics allong side google analytics to see if its a glitch with your google analytics, but this would only help going forward

Answer (score 1):

I would drill down under Traffic Sources and determine where the drop was from. Was it evenly spread between direct, referral, organic, and or paid? Or was it a single source that dropped off? If a single source you can drill down further to figure out from where. I worked with a client who had a large drop in traffic which turned out to be from Google images. All the while organics were up 20%. You should also check to make sure your not infected with any malware at http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather old question - but looking at the dates: Sometimes Google Analytics takes 24 hours to get the final numbers. Even though visits are usually almost correct right away, the page views and thus also the bounce rate are updated in the evening of the next day.

If Tebb is still around: Can you have a look a the data again and tell us if it was updated, please.

Comment: Hey Patrick, the problem was that javascript ad was forcing analytics code to fire twice in ever page, hence the double pageviews and the low bounce rate (as a lot of users were counted as two pageviews so low bounce rate).